# Self-hosted agent does not update automatically

Tags: azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have configured self-hosted agents behind a pool that has enabled "Allow agents in this pool to automatically update" option. When there are a new version, I can see that the update proccess try to upgrade agents, but nothing happens. I can´t see any error. What I can see is that new agent version is downloading, then the agent turn off-line, then on-line but the agent version is the same old version.

I can download manualy the new agent version from the build server, so I dont know what's wrong.
Please,  does anyone knows what i have to do in order to get   agents automatically updated.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what, you should update the agent manually every time to enable the new feature of it. And there is no such option for azure devops to update the private agent automatically when you make changes.

You could configure your private agent to [run as a windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-service), but that is for restarting agent. I think that is not what you want. When you make changes for agent(not restart), you have to update the agent manually.

As a suggestion, you should [suggest a feature to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) and then they will give you any feedback about the new idea.

Comment: In order to update Self-hosted agent automatically It's required to configure URLs and IPs  in Firewall/Proxy settings. Please go to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#ip-addresses-and-range-restrictions

Comment: We have an in-house DevOps 2019 server (Win server 2012R2), and the default agent is v2.153.1 (probably the version from when we installed DevOps 2 years ago). If I click the upgrade button will this upgrade the agent to the very latest version (2.206 as of today), and are there any risks in doing this? Could it break our build pipelines?

Comment: "If you're running your self-hosted agents on newer operating systems supported by .NET 6, the upgrade to the new agent version is automatic." - Microsoft

Answer (score -1):

In order to update Self-hosted agent automatically It's required to configure URLs and IPs in Firewall/Proxy settings. Please go to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#ip-addresses-and-range-restrictions